# Android tabs in sherlock fragment and charts in achartengine

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, achartengine

I am using achartengine library for drawing charts and sherlock library for swiping in the tabs,but when i switch from tab1 to tab2 and the tab2 has the pie chart displaying the data.

WHEN I SWIPE FROM TAB 1 TO TAB 2 (i.e. from right to left)
the pie chart which is set in the center in parent in .xml layout,but the problem that i am facing is that on swipe---->the pie chart also shifts to left side and its cut from the left,t Since the pan is enabled on the pie chart we can move it and realign in center.
I want that my pie chart should not gets shifted to left side and should be aligned in the center only on swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following in order to fix the behavior.

```
mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
```